# jquery - added class doesn't respond with the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best,

Can someone help me to find out, how an element with an added class can operate like a element which had the class from in the beginning? --> ($(document).ready(...)) . I think that the class isn't added to click event, but have no idea how to solve...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     ...
      $('span.del').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id')
        $("#"+id).remove()
        var input_values  = new Array();
        input_values [0]= id;
        load_page("change","taskMenu2.php",input_values,'del')
            })
     ...
  })
</script>
```

-

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" ><span class="del"></span> old </li>
    <li id="2" ><span class="del"></span> old </li>
    <li id="3" ><span class="del"></span> old </li>
    <li id="4" > NEED A DEL SPAN </li>
</ul>
```

***Now :*** 
I want to add the span with class "del" to **li** with the ID **4**.
When i click on it (the span), it should execute the function above like the other ones.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ...
   $("#4").prepend('<span class="del"></span>'); 
   ...
</script>
```

(jquery 2.1.0 min is used)

Hoping for a solution

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here since your `span` has been dynamically created:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#4').on('click', 'span.del', function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id')
        $("#"+id).remove()
        var input_values  = new Array();
        input_values [0]= id;
        load_page("change","taskMenu2.php",input_values,'del')
    });
})
```

Also, a side note for the `id` of your list items here. From the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is even more permissive, saying only that:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

So for a valid HTML markup, you can change `<li id="1" >`, `<li id="2" >` .... to something else such as `<li id="li1" >`, `<li id="li2" >...`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `.on()` function on a container element.

For example, in this case, something like this:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".del", function() { // Your code });
```

Comment: where do you've to plave it? outside the $(document).ready? And Or, if I place it outside it, does it still has to be inside the  $(document).ready ? because, won't you get then, 2 exact same pieces of code?

Comment: In $(document).ready yes, you will not duplicate any code, you should remove the `$('span.del').click(function() {` line with the part suggested as an answer (I saw that even @Unknown suggested the same answer). Tell me if I got what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event will not bind event to dynamic html elements. You should use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding event for dynamic html elements:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'span.del', function() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```